# dataSource.rowIdentities undefined is not an object React-Native

Tags: listview, reactjs, native

I tried to create `listView` like this:

```
var output = [];
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    output.push(this.catBox(i, response[i]));
}
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
self.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(output)
};

catBox(index, info) {
    let catName = info.catName;
    let icon = info.icon;
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}} key={index}>
            <View style={styles.stretch}>
                <Image style={styles.stretchRight} source={require('./img/stretch-right.png')} />
                <Image style={styles.stretchLeft} source={require('./img/stretch-left.png')} />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

But I got the error:

> dataSource.rowIdentities undefined is not an object

What is the problem here?

This is my `listView` code:

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(rowData) => <View style={styles.catsList}>{rowData}</View>}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.catsArea}>
    {cats}
</ListView>
```

Comment: renderRow suppose to return a View.
Try renderRow={(rowData) => return <View style={styles.catsList}>{rowData}</View>}

Answer (score 1):

Should be like `<ListView ... />`. No children nested.

```
<ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(rowData) => <View style={styles.catsList}>{rowData}</View>}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.catsArea}
/>
```